# How to make a select box on a form using Spring

Tags: java, spring, dojo, spring-webflow

I am new to Java and the Springs framework. Here is my question as formulated by a n00b (sorry if I sound like a second grader). I am trying to get a select drop down to appear on my form with a list of selectable countries. The data is stored in a MySQL table and contains a single column with the country name. I am obviously doing something wrong. I hope it is just an error caused by a simple thing I am missing. Thanks in advance for any help.

We are using WebFlow. I have the following in my flow XML:

```
<on-start>
  <evaluate expression="flowControllerActions.retrieveMBSAddressInfo()" result="address" />
  <evaluate expression="flowControllerActions.retrieveCountryInfo()" 
       result="flowScope.countryListing" />
</on-start>
```

**retrieveCountryInfo() looks like this:**

```
public Map<String, String> retrieveCountryInfo() throws IOException {
    LOGGER.debug("inside retrieveMBSAddressInfo");
    Map<String, String> countryInfo = (Map<String, String>) coaService.getCountryInfo();
    return countryInfo;
}
```

**coaService.getCountryInfo() looks like this:**

```
   public Map<String, String> getCountryInfo() {
        ArrayList <Country> cList = coaDao.getSelectableCountries();
        LinkedHashMap<String, String> retval = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        for ( Country c : cList){
            retval.put(c.getName(), c.getName());
            log.debug(c.getName());
        }
        return retval;
    }
```

**coaDao.getSelectableCountries()**, which populates the list looks this way:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Transactional(readOnly=true, propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
public ArrayList<Country> getSelectableCountries() {
    String myLike = "%";

    Session mySession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    ArrayList<Country> countries = (ArrayList<Country>) mySession
        .createCriteria(Country.class)
            .add(Restrictions.like("name", myLike)).list();

    return countries;
}
```

And finally, **the JSP page** tries to render the select element like this:

```
<td>
    <form:select path="country" id="country">
        <form:options items="${countryListing}"/>
    </form:select>
</td>
```

Comment: This is the error I am getting: `EL1008E:(pos 0): Field or property 'country' cannot be found on object of type 'java.util.HashMap'`

Comment: seems like on your jsp page your modelAttribute is a HashMap, which doesn't have a country field that you specified in your `path="country"`.

what object are you trying to bind this field to?

Comment: you need an object with a `String country` field to put in your modelAttribute form

Comment: As @rptmat57 says, your `<form:select>` is trying to set the "country" attribute of your form's model object. Please post your `<form:form>` tag. And/or your `<view-state model=...>`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but try something like this,

```
<td>
<form:select path="country" id="country">
    <c:forEach items="${countryListing}" var="countryMap" varStatus="status">
    <option value="${countryMap.key}">${countryMap.value}</option>
</c:forEach>
</form:select>
```

I hope this works! :)

Comment: won't solve his issue. he is trying to bind field `country` to a object that doesn't have any `country` field